# Outer product in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, outer-join

How to turn two vectors into a matrix of all combinations of their elements?

For example, vectors

```
>> A=[1;2;3]

A =

     1
     2
     3

>> B=[4;5;6]

B =

     4
     5
     6
```

Should be turned to

> > [1, 4; 1, 5; 1, 6; 2, 4; 2, 5; 2, 6; 3, 4; 3, 5; 3, 6]

ans =

```
 1     4
 1     5
 1     6
 2     4
 2     5
 2     6
 3     4
 3     5
 3     6
```

Comment: Have a look at [`meshgrid`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html). It should take you half the way (to generating all combinations).

Answer (score 4):

I'm sure there is a simpler way of doing this but... `meshgrid` will get you close and you just need to perform some array manipulation to get your result:

```
[BA, BB] = meshgrid(A,B);
[BA(:) BB(:)]
```

Answer (score 1):

An order of magnitude slower than `meshgrid`, but just to show you a different method:

```
[kron(A,ones(numel(B),1)), kron(ones(numel(A),1), B)];
```